# Boolean field indicating that record has belonging association with given field value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, rails-activerecord

**My models:**

```ruby
class CountryVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  belongs_to :user

  validates :country, uniqueness: { scope: user, message: 'already visited' }
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_visits

  ...
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :country_visits

  ...
end
```

I want each country to have a virtual attribute indicating that it has `country_visit` for given user

`Country.for(user)`

Here's my incomplete solution (raises `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException` if I try to perform `.count` on result):

```ruby
def self.for(user_id)
  Country
    .select("countries.*, country_visits.id AS visited")
    .joins(
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN country_visits ON 
      country_visits.country_id = countries.code 
      AND country_visits.user_id = #{user_id}"
    )
end
```

**Expected behavior:**

```ruby
user = User.create

#with country visit
c1 = Country.create
cv1 = CountryVisit.create(country: c1, user: user)

#without country visit
c2 = Country.create
```

results should be:

```ruby
countries = Country.for(user_id).order('created_at asc')
countries.first.visited # => true
countries.last.visited # => false
```

Comment: I don't understand what result you want to get from this query?

Comment: @Fenec My bad. Updated question with **Expected behavior**

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple problem here actually. If you look at the full error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: unrecognized token:
"#": SELECT countries.*, country_visits.id AS visited FROM "countries" LEFT 
OUTER JOIN country_visits ON country_visits.country_id = countries.id AND 
country_visits.user_id = #<User:0x007fcb357a5ed8>  ORDER BY created_at asc
```

Notice `#<User:0x007fcb357a5ed8>` that appears above? That's because in the `for` method you're passing the full user object, not the user id. And because you're writing raw SQL, active record isn't smart enough to coerce the AR object into an id.

Easiest way to fix this problem is change your country method to this:

```
def self.for(user) # <-- user
  Country
    .select("countries.*, country_visits.id AS visited")
    .joins(
      "LEFT OUTER JOIN country_visits ON 
      country_visits.country_id = countries.code 
      AND country_visits.user_id = #{user.id}"   # <-- user.id
    )
end
```

Comment: Sorry. that was a mistype in example

Comment: This is not a solution in any way and should be removed

Comment: @IvanDenisov then change your question, because right now it's the only thing that works for what you've described. ;)